# meteor: ios app starts with meteor logo

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor

I try to create my first iOS app with meteor. Therefore I added the package `meteor add-platform ios` and I started the app via `meteor run ios`.

xcode and the ios simulator are started, but I just see the meteor logo. Nothing else, no error message and I can't do anything in the app.

As this is completely new for me, my question is, if I forgot something elemental or did a big mistake.
As I don't get any error message, I don't know how to find any error...

Maybe you have some ideas for me what to do

Comment: Post screenshot of your Interface builder file (Storyboard) . What UI elements are added in your ViewController ?

Comment: with your iOS device plugged in via USB, open desktop Safari, Develop menu, select your device. Look for errors in your JS console (that would be coming from the webkit instance on the device). You might also want to `meteor run ios --mobile-server=192.168.0.100:3000` where the IP/port part is your computer on your local LAN. Port 3000 is meteor's default. When you deploy to a server hosted somewhere else you'll need to specify the domain and port, FYI

Comment: I do need to use a physical device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the app first in the browser using just the meteor command. Open the app using Chrome on localhost:3000. Open the developer tools, and there should be your logs. If those logs do not help, you may need to see the app logs.

On Android you can see the OS and App logs using Android logcat (hint use Android Studio its logcat gui has easy filters to hide the noise of other apps and the OS on the device).